# Lists conversion

Tags: prolog, flatten, gnu-prolog

I am newbie to prolog and I am trying to flatten a list which is like this:

```
X = [[[0,0,1],[1,0,2]],[[0,1,3],[0,2,2]],[[0,3,5],[0,4,4]],[[0,5,4],[0,6,5]]]
```

The desired output is:

```
X = [[0,0,1],[1,0,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,2],[0,3,5],[0,4,4],[0,5,4],[0,6,5]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion :-)

```
myflatten([], []).
myflatten([[A, B]|T], [A|[B|FlattenedT]]) :- myflatten(T, FlattenedT).
```

And then query:

?- myflatten([[[0,0,1],[1,0,2]],[[0,1,3],[0,2,2]],[[0,3,5],[0,4,4]],[[0,5,4],[0,6,5]]], X).

Comment: Here is a simple rule of thumb: Whenever you see `|[` in a program, you can replace it by `,`. The second argument in the head of myflatten thus could read `[A,B|FlattenedT]` in place of `[A|[B|FlattenedT]]`.